# Unable to reposition UIView after hiding status bar

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having issues with the positioning of the the main view of a UIViewController when hiding the status bar.  I invoke the call to hide the status bar, but the view does not translate up to occupy the space left behind by the status bar, even when trying to reposition the frame programmatically.

Below is the screenshot of the view, bordered by a blue border.  Despite my best efforts, I can't seem to translate it up to occupy the space of the status bar.  However, I do notice that when rotate the phone, then it does occupy the space fully, though I don't know what to call to achieve that when initially entering the view.  Any ideas how to reposition the view?

[image]

I hide the status bar and try to reposition the view with the following code:

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

CGRect translatedFrame = self.view.frame;
translatedFrame.origin.y -=20;
self.view.frame = translatedFrame;

[self.view.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[self.view.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

Comment: how about you try: self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frameWidth,frameHeight) and see if it works then.

Comment: Which frame width & height did you want me to set?  I tried:

self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

Comment: Simply add two NSLog to show [self.view.frame description] before and after your change.

Comment: Adding the two NSLogs shows that the origin.y and height are both 0 and 480 respectively, both before and after the call to hide the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed down the issue to a library that I'm using (View Deck).  Everyone's suggestions would work for a normal case, I think, but given that View Deck creates a container with the view controllers, I think it's not rendering correctly because of that.

Comment: What solution for View Deck did you end up going with?

Comment: @danimal: I think the issue was the parent viewDeckController (the container) was still respecting the bounds of the status bar. Try this:

    `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
        self.viewDeckController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        [self.viewDeckController.view setNeedsDisplay];
}`

Answer (score 1):

When and where are you hiding the status bar? In my experience, this is only handled correctly if the code is placed in `viewWillAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though it wasn't the issue, I think that you're correct that this is where it should be-- I previously had it in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this line for resize your view.

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

CGRect translatedFrame = self.view.frame;
translatedFrame.origin.y -=20;
translatedFrame.size.height += 20; // Add 20px
self.view.frame = translatedFrame;

[self.view.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[self.view.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

Comment: My view was originally 480px, as I had previously set the height in IB.  However, I still added the code just to see whether adjusting the height triggers the translation, but it just remained in the same location, though the height is now 20px larger.

Comment: Try this : `UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];`
`self.view.frame = window.screen.bounds;`